# Simple modular arithmetic expression proof

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove that if $N_1\mod(a) = n_1$ and $N_2\mod(a) = n_2$ then $(N_1+N_2)\mod(a) = (n_1+n_2)\mod(a)$

By our assumption $N_1 = am_1 + n_1$ and $N_2 = am_2 + n_2$

So $N_1+N_2 = a(m_1+m_2) + n_1 + n_2$

So $(N_1+N_2)\mod(a) = (a(m_1+m_2) + n_1 + n_2)\mod(a)$

Now my justification was long and considered the case where $n_1+n_2 < a$ and $= a$ and $>$ then a however the solutions I am using to check simply said both $n_1$ and $n_2$ are between $0$ and $a-1$ and so the expression is true. It feels like their reasoning is missing a few steps because I'm not sure how they can go from $n_1$ and $n_2$ between $0$ and $a-1$ to the identity is true. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please format your questions using MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: When you say $N\pmod a = n$ does that *require* that $0\le n < a$.  i.e. that $n$ is the *remainder*?  Most text *don't* require that. For most text $N \equiv n\pmod a$ just means $N$ and $n$ have the same remainder. It doesn't require one of them *is* the remainder.  e.g.  $6\equiv 10 \pmod 4$ because $6$ and $10$ both have the same remainder.

Comment: It is in the context of remainders so it requires 0 <= n < a

Comment: If $N\pmod a = n$ *DOES* require than $0 \le n < a$ then yes you have to consider if $n_1 + n_2 \ge a$.  But in that case $n_1 + n_2 = a + m_3$ for some $0\le m < a$ so $N_1 +N_2 = a(m_1+m_2 +1) + m_3$ and you are done.  But I'd say *none* of that matters.  $N_1 + N_2 = a(m_1 + m_2) + (n_1 + n_2)$ is enough.  For most texts $0 \le n_1 + n_2 < a$ is *not* a requirement.

Comment: "It is in the context of remainders so it requires 0<=n < a"  In that case you are correct.  You have to consider that maybe $a\le n_1 + n_2 < 2a$ but that's really very easy.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is my first time dealing with modular arithmetic so it was introduced in the context of remainders and the justification you gave is what I did also but was confused by how the solutions sheet jumped a few steps

Comment: It's a pet peeve of mine but in most test $a \pmod n$ is *not* an operator that gives you a specific number.  It is a statement about a characteristic $a$ might share with other numbers on the basis of what remainder it has.  When we say $a\pmod n \equiv b \pmod n$ we don't actually want to *find* the remainder.  We want to say $a$ and $b$ are equivalent and have the same properties in that they have the same remainder.

Comment: So what would the proof look like if not requiring 0 <= n < a and instead thinking about it not as an operation but as a congruence like you say most texts use?

Comment: @EBL See the *Congruence Sum Rule* linked in my answer in the dupe.